Is this minesweeper solvable? open-2-2-2-2-open

I don't know how to resolve specifically that part without helping me solve the game by the other side, and I am in doubt if it can be solved just with that information of the image

Is it possible to show the full board and also which difficulty you are playing?

Yes, It is possible but I could have done it by solving other parts of the board, however, I am specifically interested in checking if is likely to solve the board only by the given info. And The difficulty was medium. The website is mineswifter.com

theres probably an ai to solve minesweepers

With the information given, there is no way of solving this section of the Minesweeper puzzle without taking some amount of risk. There are multiple valid locations for the bombs to be, and no guaranteed safe spot.
To visualize, the below examples are both equally valid (hypothetical bombs marked with Teal), though they aren't the only valid setups for this puzzle.
Examples 1:

Example: 2

Since there is no single square which cannot contain a bomb, the puzzle is unable to be solved. Your best best is the square under the right most bomb in your picture, but that still has a 13% chance of containing a bomb.

